# The king of Goim in Gilgal or Galilee?

Tags: joshua

In Joshua 12:23 (NASB)

> the king of Dor in the heights of Dor, one; the king of Goiim in **Gilgal**, one;

In the Portuguese BPT09 translation it reads

> Dor, na costa do mar, Goim, na **Galileia**,

which translates to

> Dor, on the coast of the sea, Goim, in **Galilee**,

Ofc Gilgal isn't the same location as Galilee. What's the reason behind this difference and which is the correct region?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Joshua 12:23
New International Version

> the king of Dor (in Naphoth Dor) one the king of Goyim in **Gilgal** one

in Gilgal,
**לְגִלְגָּ֖ל** (lə·ḡil·gāl)
Preposition-l | Noun - proper - feminine singular
Strong's Hebrew 1537: Gilgal -- 'circle (of stones)', the name of several places in Palestine

English Standard Version

> the king of Dor in Naphath-dor, one; the king of Goiim in **Galilee**, one;

Galilee is from LXX:

> βασιλέα Ἐλδὼμ τοῦ Φεννεδδώρ, βασιλέα Γεεὶ τῆς **Γαλειλαίας** [Galilaia]

Gill explains that Gilgal wasn't a city:

> the king of the nations of Gilgal, one; not the place where Joshua encamped after he had passed Jordan, for that was then no city; the Septuagint version renders it the land of **Galilee**; and Dr. Lightfoot (s) is of opinion that Galilee is meant, and in the Apocrypha:"Who went forth by the way that leadeth to Galgala, and pitched their tents before Masaloth, which is in Arbela, and after they had won it, they slew much people.'' (**1 Maccabees 9:2**)Galgala is spoken of as near to Arbel, a city in Galilee: Jerom (t) takes this to be the same with Glagulis, which in his time was a village six miles from Antipatris to the north.